# C++ pointer vs array and pointer casting

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, casting

I am trying the following code:

```
unsigned long * foo = (unsigned long *) 0x200000;
```

So, as I understand it, foo points to the unsigned long 0x200000. Now, if I try,

```
std::cout<<foo[0];
```

I thought this should print the value `0x200000` (may be in decimal). Because, `foo[0] = *(foo + 0) = 0x200000`.
But, it actually prints `0`.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand,

```
unsigned long * foo = (unsigned long *) 0x200000;
```

interprets 0x200000 as the address of an `unsigned long`. Since it is extremely unlikely that that is the address of an `unsigned long` that you can legitimately access in your programme,

```
std::cout<<foo[0];
```

is almost certainly undefined behaviour, and likely causes a segfault. In your case, though, accessing that memory location didn't cause a segfault and the bits there were interpreted and printed as an `unsigned long`, they happened to be all 0.

Comment: what do you mean by 'and address'?

Comment: Typo, should have been _an_ address, _the_ address is probably better, though.

Comment: It may also be illustrative to present possible fixes, e.g.,:
unsigned long bar = 0x200000; unsigned long * foo = &bar;
Note that in such a case, care should be taken that the pointer foo is not copied outside of the scope, outliving bar and dangling.  The op would probably benefit from brushing up on the dereference operator * and address-of operator &.

Answer (score 0):

```
type * pointerName = addressItPointsTo;
```

`pointerName[0]` is same as `*pointerName`, means dereference the pointer and get the value at the address it points too. It just happens to be 0, however it usually cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: How would it react to `unsigned long * foo = &0x200000;`? Would the `0x200000` be treated as a compile-time constant like string literals in the same scenario, or would it be invalid somehow? Would you need a `const` before it? (Can't test right now)

Comment: @Ghost2 Make a simple program and try it yourself. See how compile says about getting address of a constant.